# Android share content

Tags: android

I'm trying to read the current web address and share with another app.
How to read the contents of the string **currentUrl** inside the **private Intent doShare()**?

```
private class MyCustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        String currentUrl;
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            currentUrl=url;
            return true;
        }
    }

...

private Intent doShare() {

        String SMessage1 = "xxx" ;
        String SMessage2 = "xxx" ;
        String SMessage3 = "xxx" ;
        String SMessage5 = "xxx" ;
        String SMessage6 = "xxx" ;
        String SMessage7 = "xxx" ;
        String SMessage8 = "xxx" ;
        String SMessage9 = "xxx" ;
        String SMessage10 = "xxx" ;
        String SMessage11 = "xxx" ;
        String SMessage12 = "xxx" ;

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, SMessage1 +"\n"+ SMessage2 +"\n"+ SMessage3 +"\n"+ currentUrl +"\n"+ SMessage5 +"\n"+ SMessage6 +"\n"+ SMessage7 +"\n"+ SMessage8 +"\n"+ SMessage9 +"\n"+ SMessage10 +"\n"+ SMessage11 +"\n"+ SMessage12);
        return intent;
    }

    // Call to update the share intent
    private void setShareIntent(Intent shareIntent) {
        if (mShareActionProvider != null) {
            mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not provide the full code for the class. My guess is that `MyCustomWebViewClient` is a private inner class of an `Activity`, where `doShare()` is a method on that `Activity`. In that case, move `String currentUrl` to be a data member of the `Activity`, instead of being a data member of `MyCustomWebViewClient`. `MyCustomWebViewClient` will still be able to access it, but it will also be available to the `doShare()` method.

Comment: Your solution works fine but now when I share the content of currentUrl I receive the text "null", not understand why.

Comment: @RuiBranco: Make sure that you are not resetting `currentUrl` to `null`. Make sure that you do not have multiple things named `currentUrl`.

Comment: @RuiBranco: Then I have no means to help you. Either `currentUrl` is `null` in `doShare()`, or there is some problem in your `doShare()` implementation.

Comment: not seem, the currentUrl is also null in everywhere. I can post the entire code so we can identify the problem??

Comment: @RuiBranco: I suggest that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question where you post the entire code.

Comment: @RuiBranco: You are only setting `currenturl` in `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`, which will not always be called, and particularly should not be called when loading an asset.

Comment: you can show me what to do? I lost hours to solve this because I am still learning, this is my first app.

Comment: @RuiBranco: "you can show me what to do?" -- perhaps get rid of `currenturl` entirely and call `getUrl()` on the `WebView` instead.

Comment: I tried to do this currenturl = mainWebView.getUrl(); but I can not get the url.Something I'm not understand. Sorry